# How can I read data from file ? I can't fix it

Tags: c, file, structure

I record students informations to txt file but when I want to read data's from file 
just read information's in the first row. Also I calculate the average of the students but when ı want to read average it's not working.

```
    FILE *fout;
fout = fopen("English Class.txt","w"); 

printf("Please enter student number of class : ");
scanf("%d", &x.classNum);

fprintf(fout, "Class Number : %d\n",x.classNum);

for(i=0; i<x.classNum; i++){

    printf("Please Enter %d.Student Name : ",i+1);
    scanf("%s",&x.Name);

    printf("Please Enter %d.Student Surname : ",i+1);
    scanf("%s",&x.Surname);

    printf("Please Enter %d.Student Number : ",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&x.StudentNumber);

    printf("Please Enter %d.Student Score : ",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&x.EnglishScore);

    x.total = x.total + x.EnglishScore;

    fprintf(fout, "\nStudent Name : %s %s Student Number : %d Student Score : %d\n", x.Name, x.Surname, x.StudentNumber, x.EnglishScore);
 }

x.average = x.total / x.classNum;

fprintf(fout, "\n\nClass Average is : %f", x.average);

fclose(fout);
```

I get students records from top code

```
        FILE *fin;
    fin = fopen("English Class.txt","r");


    fscanf(fin, "Class Number : %d\nStudent Name : %s %s Student Number : %d Student Score : %d\n\nClass Average is : %f",&x.classNum, &x.Name, &x.Surname, &x.StudentNumber, &x.EnglishScore, &x.average);
    fclose(fin);            


    printf("Class Number : %d\n", x.classNum);

    for(i=0; i<x.classNum; i++){

    fscanf(fin, "\nStudent Name : %s %s Student Number : %d Student Score : %d\n\nClass Average is : %f", &x.Name, &x.Surname, &x.StudentNumber, &x.EnglishScore);
    fclose(fin);    

    printf("\nStudent Name : %s %s Student Number : %d Student Score : %d\n", x.Name, x.Surname, x.StudentNumber, x.EnglishScore);  

    }

    printf("\n\nClass Average is : %f", x.average);
```

Comment: The `*scanf()` functions return a value indicating the number of assignments. Use that value for error checking: `if (fscanf(...) != EXPECTED_ASSIGNMENTS) /* report error or maybe... */ exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`

Comment: Please show a [mcve] as well as a minimal sample of the file you read. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary **to reproduce it, that includes input files**, in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

As of now you are closing the `file` immediately after reading each time.

```
    fscanf(fin, "Class Number : %d\nStudent Name : %s %s Student Number : %d Student Score : %d\n\nClass Average is : %f",&x.classNum, &x.Name, &x.Surname, &x.StudentNumber, &x.EnglishScore, &x.average);

   fclose(fin)
```

Then you try to use same `FILE` pointer to read in causing undefined behavior.

---

Close the File only after you finished your processing.

Comment: There may be more bugs though....

Comment: @Jabberwocky I agree, this bug I thought should be highlighted without [mcve].